# Can not copy link to answer or comment without inspecting HTML

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, user-interface, hyperlinks

It's hard to understand that "share" has a link to the answer. In comparison to a forum, which has a link to the post on the top of the post.

It would be more handy if the "share" link was near the post score.

Actually I sometimes need a link to a comment, such as:
`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261243/make-vote-number-active-which-has-link-to-this-answer#comment-851859`

How do I copy the link to a comment or answer? Can someone improve the interface for that?

Comment: No idea what you mean. What do you want? Why? Please [edit] and clarify

Comment: I assume that by "vote number" you mean the post score... Clicking on the post's score (when you have [>1K rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)) will show you how the score is calculated; ie how many down/up votes have been made. So this UI element already has some functionality attached to it.

Comment: If you really want an element that links to the post at the very top of the page, you can always use the post title - it links directly to the post.

Comment: @Lix is right on spot, was going to add such comment. Also, having the score be a permalink is even less intuitive than "share". Far less.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - oh... I think the OP is specifically referencing **answers**. Other than the share link, there isn't really any other permalinks available for answers...

Comment: May be move 'share' to top of answer?

Comment: @Lix duh! You're right. I would support making the "answered" text permalink to the answer, same as share, that can be copied like comment timestamp. :)

Comment: I'll mark this as [tag:status-bydesign], because for the most part, it is. However, I imagine having the "N hours ago" text in the "answered" and "asked" boxes (same behavior as in comments could *make sense*), though I'm not sure how *useful* it might be. If this is behavior you'd like to see, feel free to make a separate meta post so we can measure community support for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It will be more handy if 'vote number' will has link to this answer.

No, the vote number click already has a purpose: show the vote count when having enough reputation. It seems illogical too to put a link there.

> May be move 'share' to top of answer?

No, not useful in my opinion. I always read the answer first before I want to copy the link, so the current link in the bottom of the post is the most logical to me.

> How to copy link to comment or answer?

To copy the link to a question or an answer you can click the *Share* button. For comments you can click on the *X mins ago* and your browser will navigate to the URL you need to link that comment. You can copy/paste that from your browser's address bar. Or right-click on the comment and hit *Copy Link* or something similar in your browser.

Comment: Never think that Xmins is a link =). Whole comment is link - this is expected, but X mins...

Comment: +1 Additionally (@EugenKonkov) the "Share" link is with other links relating to the answer or question, such as "flag" "edit" etc. Moving one means we split functional links up into different areas. They're pretty useful where they are IMO

Comment: Agree with @James. This would really mess things up.

Comment: @EugenKonkov: Note that using timestamps as permalinks is very common across all sorts of discussion software -- blogs, fora, and so forth. So while it's not immediately obvious, it's a) a useful convention and b) fairly practical to remember given the idea that "posted at such-and-such a time" maps fairly cleanly to "a way to always get to this post", i.e. a permalink.